# need to fetch country and state dropdown in contact form magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, module, contact-form, magento2.4.3

need to fetch country and state drop down in contact form in magento 2.4.3
it showcase & fetches state for default country but could not fetch any other selected country from drop down .

code for form.phtml

```
<?php
$countryList=$block->getCountries();
$regionList=$block->getRegion();  ?>
<form class="form retuns"
    action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormAction(); ?>"
    id="return-form"
    method="post"
    data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>"
    data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
        <div class="field country required">
            <label class="label" for="country"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Country') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <?php echo $countryList?>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field region required">
            <label class="label" for="state"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('State') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <?php echo $regionList?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field states required" style="display:none">
            <label class="label" for="states"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('State') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="state" id="states" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('State') ?>"  class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
<script>
    require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function(){
    jQuery(document).on('change','#country',function() {
        var param = 'country='+jQuery('#country').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            showLoader: true,
            url: '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getRegion(); ?>',
            data: param,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json'
        }).success(function (data) {
            alert(data.value);
            if(data.value=='')
            {
                jQuery('.field.states.required').show();
                jQuery('.field.region.required').hide();
            }
            else
            {
                jQuery('#state').append(data.value);
                jQuery('.field.states.required').hide();
                jQuery('.field.region.required').show();
            }
        }).error(function(data){
            alert('blank');
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

code for contactForm.php

```
<?php
namespace Dcwilkinson\CustomContact\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class ContactForm extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
  protected $directoryBlock;
  protected $_isScopePrivate;  
    
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Directory\Block\Data $directoryBlock,
    array $data = []
  )
  {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    $this->directoryBlock = $directoryBlock;
  }
  public function getCountries()
  {
    $country = $this->directoryBlock->getCountryHtmlSelect();
    return $country;
  }
  public function getRegion()
  {
    $region = $this->directoryBlock->getRegionSelect();
    return $region;
  }
  public function getCountryAction()
  {
    return $this->getUrl('contact', ['_secure' => true]);
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**heres the update**
try this solution it work for us
https://magebug.blogspot.com/2018/04/magento-2-how-to-display-country.html